# Find images with same exif timestamp

Tags: command-line, files, timestamps, exif

How can I find all groups of images which have the same exif timestamp in a given directory from the command line in linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, let's say you are using [exiftool](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool) and a command like

```
exiftool -sep $'\t' -T -filename -createdate dir
```

This prints one line per image in directory `dir` with the filename and its creation timestamp. I don't know if this is the timestamp you had in mind but you can always change that field.

Pipe output of that command to this `awk` command

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "\t" }{ datetime = $2 " " $3 } { files[datetime] = files[datetime] " " $1 } END { for (time in files) print time ":" files[time] }'
```

...like so...

```
exiftool -sep $'\t' -T -filename -createdate dir | awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "\t" }{ datetime = $2 " " $3 } { files[datetime] = files[datetime] " " $1 } END { for (time in files) print time ":" files[time] }'
```

And you'll get output of the form

```
2016:05:05 00:52:03: IMG_0990.JPG IMG_0962.JPG
2016:05:05 00:51:23: IMG_0965.JPG
2016:05:05 00:48:36: IMG_0956.JPG IMG_0966.JPG IMG_0969.JPG
```

*Note: For the sake of simplicity/sanity I am assuming that the image filenames don't have spaces in them or any other funkiness.*

*Disclaimer: I'm not an `awk` expert. There may be more elegant ways to do the same thing.*

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure that the first exiftool command is correct? For me it prints only a \t?

Comment: @student I updated with a different `exiftool` command and a tweak to the `awk` part to accommodate it. I tested this locally with some images and it's working here. One thing, though, is createdate is probably going to be different for every photo unless you copied them. So choose another tag from the exif data if you need to.